# NLog - Help Understanding existing configuration options

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog on an application.  I copied over NLog configuration settings from another project.  The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

  <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
  <!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

  <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/log.txt" />
        <target name="errors" xsi:type="File" maxArchiveFiles="7" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${message}|${exception:format=ShortType,StackTrace}" archiveEvery="Day" fileName="${basedir}\logs\exceptions.txt" />    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file,errors" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm curious what the configuration is specifying, in particular the "archive" options.  (i.e. maxArchiveFiles, archiveEvery).

Also, I noticed that currently when I log *anything* using NLog, it spits out two files.  An exceptions.txt file and a log.txt file.  I guess I expected that the exceptions file would only contain exceptions (it logs warnings and information to the exceptions text file).

Right now I'm only logging errors/exceptions, so I don't think I even need the logs.txt file if its just the same thing as the exceptions.txt.

C#, NLog v2.0.0.0, ASP.NET 4

Comment: Have you gone to NLog at all and read about the config file? http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file

Answer (score 0):

It's creating two files (logs.txt and errors.txt) because you're specifying two files (target name=file, target name=errors).

That's probably a good idea, but you're certainly free to experiment with different combinations of settings and files, and standardize on whatever suits you best.

Here's the documentation explaining the format and options:

- http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file